# exercise of eigenvalues ,

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A ∈ \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $A^2 =-I$, where I is the identity matrix of order n.

(a) Determine all eigenvalues of A.

(b) Prove that matrix A has a trace equal to 0 and a determinant equal to 1.

sol.

(correct if something is wrong in the solution, and please can help in the questions I ask throughout the solution)

let $(\lambda,v)$ is any eigenpair of A, then

$Av=\lambda v \quad \Rightarrow \quad $ $A^2v=\lambda ^2 v \quad  $ $\Rightarrow \quad $ $-v=\lambda ^2 v $

therefore $\lambda =\pm  i$ the eigenvalues are $\quad i \quad$   and $\quad-i \quad$ 
but    $A ∈ \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ can be these eigenvalues of A?

if  the eigenvalues are $\quad i \quad$   and $\quad-i \quad$  then n can not be odd since it has only complex eigenvalues(n it can not be odd, if it were odd it would have a real eigenvalue but this does not happen because the eigenvalues are complex).

then $n$ is even number.  $n=2m$

$\Rightarrow \lambda _1 = i\quad $ has algebraic multiplicity equal to m

and

$\Rightarrow \lambda _1 = -i\quad $ has algebraic multiplicity equal to m.

since the complex eigenvalues have to be with their conjugate

therefore

$trace(A)=0$  and  $ det(A)=1$,

since the trace of A is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues of A

can you help with the questions I asked please.

Comment: Fine, but have you explained why the algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ are the same?

Comment: If det(A)=1 then det(A^2)=1 but det (-I)=-1 for n odd. Hence b) is false.

Comment: n it can not be odd, if it were odd it would have a real eigenvalue but this does not happen because the eigenvalues are complex

Comment: each complex eigenvalue has to be with its conjugate, that is why the algebraic multiplicity of $i$ is $m$ and of $-i$ is $m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the matrix is real, its characteristic polynomial is real, and a real polynomial has either real solutions or complex solutions in conjugate pairs. The latter is the case for your matrix, as $\pm i$ are the only candidates. Thus, $+i$ and $-i$ occur in pairs and must therefore be equal in number.

This also proves your finding that $n$ must be even, and gives the trace and the determinant.